# Xbox live updates fails over and over

Tags: xbox-360

I keep trying to download the latest Xbox Live Update and it keeps failing.

I have done a test connection and when it gets the part where it tests the Xbox Live it says there is an update.  I try to down load it and it will eventually fail (on the second screen after attempt 3 of 3).

This is the useless status code it gives me:

3143-3151-A080-0F00-8007-2EE2

Is this code really useful for any form of support of help? All xbox.com/support does is try to reconfigure my hardware.  My Hardware is connecting to the internet and xbox live just fine (I get part of the update).

What I can I do to get real support, not just canned wizards that assume the problem is on my hardware?

Comment: I'm having this problem on a system that's brand new and has never connected to the internet before. Status Code: 4099-416b-a080-0f00-8007-2ee2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [clearing the system cache](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971755)? You may have a corrupt update that causes the problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, empyting the cache doesn't do anything.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds Like you need to open NAT on your router to me.

Comment: NAT type is open (has been for a good long while).